# Wall Dimensioning

Tags: revit-api, revit, revit-2015

I would like to set the gap from the element to some value so that the dimension would be clearly visible. Please find below the screen shot.

Currently it's looking like this.

[image: Currently it's looking like this]

But I would like to achieve like below.

[image: But I would like to achieve like below]

Answer (score 0):

You are actually in control of the line when you create the dimension.  Take a line from Revit then transform it and offset it perpendicular to the line you're interested in: (Given a dbView and a reference array and a curve)

```
//create your line along the element you want to dimension
Line line = Line.CreateBound(locCurve.Curve.GetEndPoint(0), locCurve.Curve.GetEndPoint(1));

//Compute the perpendicular of that line (I took advantage of the fact that I was working in plan:
XYZ perpendicular = line.ComputeDerivatives(0.5, true).BasisX.CrossProduct(new XYZ(0, 0, 1));

//transform the line to the new offset location:
Line offsetline = line.CreateTransformed(Transform.CreateTranslation(perpendicular.Normalize())) as Line;

//Create the dimension.
revitDoc.Create.NewDimension(dbView, offsetline, aDimensionRefArray);
```